# Meteor Aldeed autoform array as checkbox group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have an edit/new form that I want to update a mongo document within my collection.

The videos collection - each has an array of genres [1,2,3] where I insert a genre id into each video.

I have two schema, one for genre and one for video

I am using autoform to give me the fields and twitter bootstrap

I can't get the autoform to display the genre in the edit or new forms.

code below:

```
  genres: {
type: [Genres],
label: "Genre",
autoform: {
    type: 'checkbox',
    options: function () {
      return Genres.find().map(function (g) {
        return {label: g.name, value: g._id};
      });
  }
},
optional: true
```

},

in the form I have

```
{{> afQuickField name="genres" type="checkbox" options="genres" noselect=true}}
```

all the other fields work fine, data comes through.